# Architecture for providing different linear algebra back-ends

Tags: python, architecture, linear-algebra, backend, metaclass

I am prototyping a new system in Python; the functionality is mostly numerical.

An important requirement is the ability to use different linear algebra back-ends: from individual user implementations to generic libraries, such as Numpy. The linear algebra implementation (that is, the back-end) must be independent from the interface.

My initial architectural attempt is as follows:

#### (1) Define the system interface

```
>>> v1 = Vector([1,2,3])
>>> v2 = Vector([4,5,6])
>>> print v1 * v2
>>> # prints "Vector([4, 10, 18])"
```

#### (2) Implement the code allowing to use that interface independently of the back-end

```
# this example uses numpy as the back-end, but I mean
# to do this for a general back-end
import numpy 
def numpy_array(*args): # creates a numpy array from the arguments
    return numpy.array(*args)

class VectorBase(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        engine = attrs.pop("engine", None)
        if not engine:
            raise RuntimeError("you need to specify an engine")
        # this implementation would change depending on `engine`
        def new(cls, *args):
            return numpy_array(*args)   
        setattr(cls, "new", classmethod(new))

class Vector(object):   
    __metaclass__ = VectorBase        
    # I could change this at run time
    # and offer alternative back-ends
    engine = "numpy"  
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, v):
        nv = cls()
        nv._v = v
        return nv    
    def __init__(self, *args):  
        self._v = None
        if args:
            self._v = self.new(*args)
    def __repr__(self):
        l = [item for item in self._v]
        return "Vector(%s)" % repr(l)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        try:
            return Vector.create(self._v * other._v)
        except AttributeError:
            return Vector.create(self._v * other)
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)
```

This simple example works as follows: the `Vector` class keeps a reference to a vector instance made by the back-end (`numpy.ndarray` in the example); all arithmetic calls are implemented by the interface, but their evaluation is deferred to the back-end.

In practice, the interface overloads all the appropriate operators and defers to the back-end (the example only shows `__mul__` and `__rmul__`, but you can follow that the same would be done for every operation).

I am willing to loose some performance in exchange of customizability. Even while my example works, it does not feel right -- I would be crippling the back-end with so many constructor calls! This begs for a different `metaclass` implementation, allowing for a better call deferment.

So, how would you recommend that I implement this functionality? I need to stress the importance of keeping all of the system's `Vector` instances homogeneous and independent of the linear algebra back-end.

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that your current implementation is keeping the `Vector` instances independent of the back-end. Quite the contrary, each one is a `numpy_array`. Seems to me that to do this would require either a separate back-end-independent representation to be maintained or an interface for each type and its attributes present in the system -- which would likely be more that just `Vectors`...`Matrix` immediately comes to mind, for example. If this is correct, can you enumerate them?

Comment: Since you've already awarded the bounty (as well as ignored my question), I -- and likely most others -- are dissuaded to provide any further help or input.

Comment: @martineau: sorry, away from computer access for a while. As for your question, the example I present is can definitively be improved. What I am looking for is a way to (1) truly decouple interface from back-end (it seems that I will go with metaclasses), and (2) avoid crippling the backend. So, what's your take? A design pattern like "Strategy" using regular objects, or a metaclass, or abstract base classes, or a combination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out [PEP-3141](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/) and the standard lib module [ABCMeta](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html).

For a detailed explanation of how to use ABCMeta, the always helpful [PyMOTW](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/abc/) has a nice write-up.

Comment: Yes, I have been experimenting with ABCs, and they may be the way to go, but I am still not 100% convinced that I will marry this approach. The issue is that ABCs still impose a "layer" which may cripple the linear algebra back-end. I may just need to play with three approaches: metaclass, abstract class, and ABCs and profile them. Thanks.

Comment: The bounty is yours, but I still need more input on the architecture (in addition to the mechanism for implementing an abstract interface).

Comment: Ok Arrieta, I'll write something up and add a more detailed answer to cover it. Please keep the question unlocked.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply make a "virtual" class (`AbstractVector`) which is like Vector in your example, and make different subclasses of it for each implementation?

An engine could be chosen by doing `Vector = NumPyVector` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, you can easily configure and build NumPy to use Intel's Math Kernel Library or AMD's Core Math Library instead of the usual ATLAS + LAPACK.  This is as simple as creating a [site.cfg](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/site.cfg.example) file with the `blas_libs`, `lapack_libs`, `library_dirs`, and `include_dirs` variables set appropriately. (Details for setting these options for MKL and ACML are readily Googleable.) Place it alongside the `setup.py` script and build as usual.

To switch between these standard linear algebra libraries, you could build a different instance of NumPy for each and manage them using [virtualenvs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), for example.

I know that doesn't give you the flexibility you need to use your own custom math libraries, but just thought I'd throw that out there.  And though I haven't looked into it, I imagine you might also be able to get NumPy to build against a custom library with less effort than it would take to build your own front-end, especially if you want to retain the extensive functionality of the NumPy/SciPy edifice.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful - not so much because it solves my problem, but because I can refer to the NumPy source code and see how they did it ;) - that may very well be the answer to my question.